# Read from specific Kafka topic using Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have topic with 3 partitions and I'm trying to read from each specific partition using following code

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, TopicPartition

brokers = 'localhost:9092'
topic = 'b3'

m = KafkaConsumer(topic, bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
par = TopicPartition(topic=topic, partition=1)
m.assign(par)
```

but I am getting this error:

```
    raise IllegalStateError(self._SUBSCRIPTION_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE)
kafka.errors.IllegalStateError: IllegalStateError: You must choose only one way to configure your consumer: (1) subscribe to specific topics by name, (2) subscribe to topics matching a regex pattern, (3) assign itself specific topic-partitions.
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

Can you remove the topic parameter from KafkaConsumer() and try again?

example:

```
# manually assign the partition list for the consumer
from kafka import TopicPartition, KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:1234')
consumer.assign([TopicPartition('foobar', 2)])
msg = next(consumer)
```

ref: http://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: How would you insert timeout feature here? I would like to stop the streaming process if no new message has appeared for example 1s.

Comment: Look into `poll` function, it allows you to set a timeout.
http://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html?highlight=poll#kafka.KafkaConsumer.poll

Comment: btw: Did I answer you original question? :-)